# Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException startPreview failed

Tags: android, android-camera

I have used 
com.wonderkiln.camerakit.CameraView in one of my application, mostly it's working fine but in some devices it's crashing with the below stack trace.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
startPreview failed


android.hardware.Camera.startPreview (Camera.java)
com.wonderkiln.camerakit.Camera1.start (Camera1.java:130)
com.wonderkiln.camerakit.CameraView$2.run (CameraView.java:266)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:754)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:165)
android.os.HandlerThread.run (HandlerThread.java:61)
```

If someone faced it then please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to upgrade the version of the library. In the latest version issue is not seen.